# container start up failed in jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, cmd, war

When I use the command prompt in windows to run the command `java -jar jenkins.war` It is giving me the following error:

```
SEVERE: Container startup failedjava.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at Main._main(Main.java:293)
    at Main.main(Main.java:132)Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:152)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: "at Main.main(Main.java:132)Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind" Change the port of your jetty server in pom.xml file.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The cause of your error:

> Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

Explanation: As a default, Jenkins uses the port 8080 (like many other web applications do, too). Obviously, you already have another application listening on port 8080.

So you should bind Jenkins to another port. See [Starting and Accessing Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins) for more information. For example, you can start with

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: You can also check where the default port 8080 is used by running the command(`ss -lnt | grep 8080`) and stop it if not required and rerun your `java -jar jenkins.war`:

Answer (score 0):

cd into your jenkins folder from your terminal(Where you installed it)

```
cd jenkins
```

then in your terminal change the port(Whatever port you want to use):

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090
```

Jenkins will change ports and restart.And run without any errors.

Load jenkins from your browser:

```
http://localhost:9090
```

Also this error sometimes occurs when you have not completed the full installation of jenkins.At the point where jenkins chooses a random browser to continue with installation,just follow along and use the browser its chosen to open and complete the installation following the screen prompts.Once installation is completed,you have the freedom to use whatever browser you see fit.

Another thing to keep in mind is:If you had a previous installation of jenkins before the one you just installed,you need tocheck and ensure all the old jenkins files were deleted and cleaned out of your system before initializing the new installation.

Answer (score -1):

this port is already used in some other services.
you can start jenkins server any port using below command
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081